# DesignerSerializationVisibility support for Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, serialization, custom-controls, windows-phone

I want to create a custom control with a collection property, and using like this:

```
<my:mycontrol>

  <my:ctlIem />

  <my:ctlIem />

  <my:ctlIem />

  ...

  </my:mycontrol/>
```

I googled and find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437004/how-to-make-a-user-control-property-of-type-collectionmyclass-editable-in-form), but when i coded as it said, the editor returned an error with `DesignerSerializationVisibility` not found.

So, was it the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` property not supported in the Windows Phone? If it was not supported, how could I implement that feature?